# Gulp: Several compilations in one task

Tags: gulp

I have one CSS manipulation in a CSS task. Now I need to have one more, and I want to place it in the same gulp task. But it's not working.

Original code:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('./assets/css/*.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(size())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
});
```

What I want to achieve:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('./assets/css/*.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(size())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'))
        /* Handle CSS from custom directory */
        .pipe(gulp.src('./assets/css/templates/*.css'))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(size())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/templates/'));
});
```

But the CSS from the `templates` folder don't get copied to the `templates` output folder.

Comment: keep the two manipulation in two separate task, create a third one which depends on these two tasks

Comment: Just replace `'./assets/css/*.css'` in your original code with `'./assets/css/**/*.css'`.

Comment: @Sven, I can do this and handle all css files recursively, but the destination will be one and the same ... :) ... and I want to re-create the folders recursively as well ... :)

Comment: @peshohristov All folders from your source directory will be recreated in your destination directory. Try it.